# QT how to get rid of spaces between widgets and their parents

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I love designing my userinterfaces in qtdesigner because its just so damn simple. However, there is always space in between widgets and their parents which i want to eliminate.

**Example of problem**

- I create a simple dialog and add a webview to it. Then layout horizontally.

  To make the parent more obvious I modify its css to make its background color green

Voila, I want to get rid of the green sections because in my view they make the program look ugly.
[image: ugly image]
Link to my ui file.
[Download ui file from my dropbox](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51343591/problematic.ui)
or [get it from pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nTykFHi5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt Designer, select your top level widget (in this case `Dialog`), then look at the **Property Editor** on the right-hand sidebar. Scroll all the way down and you'll see a section referring to the layout assigned to that widget. You want to change the `layoutLeftMargin`, `layoutRightMargin`, etc. properties.